# how to implement this observer pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have 4 classes, that describe state diagram. `Node`, `Edge`, `ComponentOfNode` and `ComponentOfEdge`.

`ComponentOfEdge` compounds from `ComponentsOfNode`. `Node` can have 0..n outgoing edges. `Edge` can have only 2 `Nodes`.

`Edge` should be able to offer `ComponentOfNode`, but only from `Nodes` that `Edge` has, in the form of `ComponentOfEdge`.

The user can change `ComponentsOfNode`. I need this change spreads to all `Edges`. How would I do it? I expect the observer pattern should be used.

Can you give me an example in pseudo-code please?

Answer (score 2):

You know, in Java, the best example of an `Observer`/`Observable` pattern (and the easies to use in non-Swing code) is the `propertyChange[Event/Listener/Support]` trinity. It is documented (unfortunately on a Swing example, leading to confusion) in the official [Java tutorial](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html).

Answer (score 0):

Observer is a pretty simple pattern.  All you need to do is implement a method in the observing class that is called by the observed class on a change.

In your case, you might have:

```
class Edge {
  // class definition

  public void nodeChanged(Node changed) {

    // do stuff

   }
}

class Node {
  // class definition

  protected void onChange() {

    for (Edge e : myEdges) {
      e.nodeChanged(this);
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi  make one interface or  use java's default observer interface.I advice you to implement  your observer.

```
interface INodeListener{
void update(Object obj);
}
```

Node Listeners  should be implement this interface. in your node you should  hold   it's listener.When changed Node   make invoke listener method.

```
    public void invokeListener() {
       for(INodeListener listener:listeners)
        listener.update(yourVariable);
    }
```

Comment: You forgot the registerListener(INodeListener listener) :)